# Are 20V batteries of Parkside Performance series and Parkside X20V Team series compatible?

Tags: tools

Parkside Performance series is a newer series with better motor and longer-lasting battery than with Parkside X20V Team series. I am trying to find out whether the older batteries of the old generation Parkside tools work with the new generation Performance series.

[image]

I could see that Parkside Performance series has 4 pins while the Parkside X20V Team series has 3 pins in the charger so they may not be compatible in the charging. The picture is from the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REcsrlH7TNQ) but no mention about the backward compability.

**Are the Parkside 20V batteries in Parside Performance series and Parkside X20V Team series compatible?**

Comment: I'm in ireland have lots of parkside tools...just bought for 50 euro black impact gun 20v ..
Works fine with my batterys....one thing I noticed have the black cordless 20v angle grinder or 20v performance type with the 4 ah battery is an animal with power....I have a parkside green 20v angle grinder supplied with 2 ah battery its useless....if I put 4 ah battery battery for black 20v performance type....she is an animal....strange....i know that ah is amp hours as in the time ya should get from a full charge...but ya should still get the same punch from the battery as the 20v performance large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not. Locking mechanism has a different shape.

Answer (score 1):

Seems they are unifying it, now the team has black color and 4 pins (end of 2019) but now the old preformance series is not compatible with the new one. Ended up with a crap worth of 400$...

Answer (score 1):

I just bought the Cordless Combi Hammer Drill (PKHAP 20Li-A1) which is the "Performance" series of Parkside tools.
I bought it because I already have the angle grinder and drill/screw machine. Both from the "Performance" series.

And I'm very disappointed to see that the new Performance Series uses the old line of batteries "X 20V Team". And my first 2 Performance tools uses the newer Samsung batteries which are not compatible with the "X 20V Team".

- X 20V Team = "Powerful lithium-ion battery with 3-stage charge status display"
- Performance (1st series) = "Powerful lithium-ion battery with high-quality Samsung battery cells"

So, they quit the Samsung batteries to go back to the old "X 20V Team" batteries.

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately they are not compatible I purchased the new performance drill to replace my 20v team drill and was disappointed to find the battery’s are not interchangeable. Physically the mount s slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

The parkside performance range tools will take the ordinary parkside x20v team batteries, same mounting, no problem. Physically and electrically compatible.[image]